# BASH - A variable as part of array name (part 2)

Tags: arrays, bash

Let's say I start with just `item1=('item1' '1' '20')`

I then define `itemnumber=2`

I would like to create the next array as `item$itemnumber=('item2' '4' '77')`, but I get a syntax error.

After that I would like to just do `itemnumber=$((itemnumber+1))`, and create `item$itemnumber=('item3' '17' '15')`

Which would give me three arrays item1, 2 and 3:

```
item1=('item1' '1' '20')
item2=('item2' '4' '77')
item3=('item3' '17' '15')
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Which release of bash, specifically? In 4.3 and newer, there's a `namevar` feature (borrowed from ksh) which allows a more robust implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `declare` command, although you'll need to modify how you perform the assignment.

```
declare -a "item$itemnumber"
declare "item$itemnumber+=(item$itemnumber 4 77)
```

In `bash` 4.3, this is greatly simplified with named references.

```
itemnumber=0
declare -n arr=item$itemnumber
arr+=(item$itemnumber 1 20)
((itemnumber++))
declare -n arr=item$itemnumber
arr+=(item$itemnumber 4 77)
((itemnumber++))
declare -n arr=item$itemnumber
arr+=(item$itemnumber 17 15)
```

Just increment `itemnumber`, reset the reference, then use the reference as you would the actual array.

Comment: Now that I got Bash 4.3, the named references work magic! My game can now progress.

Answer (score 5):

A task for eval:

```
itemnumber=1
(( itemnumber += 1))
eval "item$itemnumber=('item$itemnumber' '4' '77')"
eval echo \${item$itemnumber[*]}
```

Comment: Thank you, klashxx. So easy :D

Answer (score 1):

A bit late answer, but if you need this many times, you can use an function for assign

```
#!/bin/bash

assign () { eval "$1=($(printf '"%s" ' "$@"))"; }

itemnum=0
assign item$((++itemnum)) 1 2 3 4
assign item$((++itemnum)) 'q w e r'
assign item$((++itemnum)) a "$itemnum cc" dd  

#show the array members enclosed in ''
echo "item1:" $(printf "'%s' " "${item1[@]}")
echo "item2:" $(printf "'%s' " "${item2[@]}")
echo "item3:" $(printf "'%s' " "${item3[@]}")
```

prints

```
item1: 'item1' '1' '2' '3' '4'
item2: 'item2' 'q w e r'
item3: 'item3' 'a' '3 cc' 'dd'
```

or simple

```
echo ${item1[@]}
echo ${item2[@]}
echo ${item3[@]}
```

prints

```
item1 1 2 3 4
item2 q w e r
item3 a 3 cc dd
```

if you want exclude, the first element from the array (the itemname), use

```
assign () { var="$1"; shift 1; eval "$var=($(printf '"%s" ' "$@"))"; }

n=0
assign item((++n)) 1 2 3 4
echo "item1 contains only: $item1[@]}"
```

prints

```
item1 contains only: 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash 4.3, a `namevar` is the perfect tool:

```
set_item() {
  local itemnumber=$1; shift
  local -n array_name="item$itemnumber"
  array_name=( "$@" )
}
set_item 2   1 2 3 4
set_item 3   2 3 4 5
```

...will have the same effect as...

```
item2=( 1 2 3 4 )
item3=( 2 3 4 5 )
```